# PHP pass input string which has spaces to python file

Tags: php, python

I am getting strings through an HTML form and storing them in PHP varibles using:

```
$var1=$_GET['name']
```

Now I pass these strings to a python script using

```
shell_exec("python_file.py $var1")
```

Suppose, string received in PHP is something like`hello world`. when the variable is passes to the python file. Python thinks of it as 2 different arguments like :

```
    ##python code
arg=sys.argv
print arg[0] -> python_file.py
print arg[1] -> 'hello'
print arg[2] -> 'world'
```

what is a workaround for this ?
I tried passing the sting into additional quotes. But it does not help.
I have not added any `split()` function in the python code.

EDIT:
The variable are entries in the database. The python script opens the database and the variable defines the corresponding changes. So if the python file reads one variable as 2 due to whitespace. It adds incorrect entries in incorrect columns in the database

Comment: Use quotes: `shell_exec('python_file.py "$var1"')` - Last quote is the simple quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you might want to use quotes:

`shell_exec('python_file.py "'.$var1.'"')` - last quote is the simple quote

You can also use [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) which will adequately prepare the argument for the shell, doing what I said, and more so that even quotes are properly passed in arguments.

It is the recommended solution for passing arguments from user input and will avoid disasters such as [escape-shell vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection).

What I tried:

test.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

exec.php:

```
<?php $arg = "hello world";
print(shell_exec('python3 test.py '.escapeshellarg($arg))); ?>
```

In my shell:

> $php5 exec.php
>
> ['test.py', 'hello world']

Comment: Did you try escapeshellarg?

Comment: yes i tried that. But this concatenates the python program and the variable .I am getting an error as "No file found as test.pyvar1" I have made a small edit to the question for additional details

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to workaround with spaces. I used string concatenation in PHP.
Python does not split arguments based on spaces if they are enclosed within quotes.

Here is precisely what i did:

```
$var=$_GET["var"];
$var="'".$var."'";
```